# How can I prevent transitions from delaying page loading?

Tags: svelte, sapper, svelte-transition

I've a problem related with Sapper's routing and Svelte's transitions.

I created a small Sapper website with just 2 pages.
On the homepage I got a Carousel component. Each one of its slides has a `in:fade={{duration: 2000}}` and a `out:fade={{duration: 2000, delay: 1000}}`.

When the page first loads there is no transition and this is perfect.

The issue comes when I navigate to let's say /contacts, before I even start seeing the Contacts page, I've to wait 3 seconds of fade out.
When the transition is complete then I can see the page.

Is this behaviour normal? Can I avoid it somehow?
I ended up using just CSS transitions but I'd prefer using svelte-transition :)

Comment: problem solved I needed to use ```out:fade|local```

Answer (score 8):

The solution (as mentioned in [the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017132/how-can-i-prevent-transitions-from-delaying-page-loading#comment100567674_57017132)) is to apply the `local` modifier to the transition.

The `local` modifier causes the transition to only be run when the local 'block' containing the carousel component is destroyed, rather than when parent blocks (e.g. the page) are destroyed – which occurs on navigation. This behaviour is detailed in [the API documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#Transition_events) and demonstrated in [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/local-transitions).